# ServiceStack include another razor page in razor page

Tags: razor, servicestack

I want to include a typed model sub-page in a razor page. I know SS is not the same as MVC razor. The way to do it maybe somewhat different.

So far, this is what I've figured out (looks ugly, iknow...):

```
    //this is somewhere in your default.cshtml
    @{
        //grab your service from Ioc
        using(var service = Get<RockstarsService>()) {
            //execute the service to get a response
            var resp = service.Get(new Rockstars());
            //call the partial razor page Rockstar.cshtml
            <p>@Html.Partial("Rockstars",resp)</p>
            //or @Html.Partial("Rockstars") will do, seems like the resp is cached anyway 
            //or @Include("Rockstars",resp) will work, too.
        }
    }
```

This solution **WORKS** with a typed model sub-page, **on the condition** that the sub-page doesn't contain any html helpers.

However, if the sub-page has html helpers like

```
@Html.Label("sometag") //PROBLEM HERE <---------------------
```

Or

```
@Html.TextBox("name","text") //PROBLEM HERE <---------------------
```

Then it will throw Server Error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Could not execute partial: Rockstars, model: RazorRockstars.WebHost.RockstarsResponse
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not execute partial: Rockstars, model: RazorRockstars.WebHost.RockstarsResponse

Source Error: An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: [InvalidOperationException: Could not execute partial: Rockstars, model: RazorRockstars.WebHost.RockstarsResponse]
   ServiceStack.Razor.Templating.TemplateService.RenderPartial(T model, String name) +333
   ServiceStack.Razor.RazorFormat.RenderPartial(String pageName, Object model, Boolean renderHtml, IHttpRequest httpReq) +433
   ServiceStack.Html.HtmlHelper.Partial(String viewName, Object model) +117
   CompiledRazorTemplates.Dynamic.fdbaecbccda.Execute() +454
   ServiceStack.Razor.Templating.TemplateService.ExecuteTemplate(T model, String name, String defaultTemplatePath, IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes) +457
   ServiceStack.Razor.RazorFormat.ExecuteTemplate(T model, String name, String templatePath, IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes) +117
   ServiceStack.Razor.RazorFormat.ProcessRazorPage(IHttpRequest httpReq, ViewPageRef razorPage, Object dto, IHttpResponse httpRes) +142
   ServiceStack.Razor.RazorHandler.ProcessRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, String operationName) +535
   ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Support.EndpointHandlerBase.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +264
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +341
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

(Bloody VS Razor breakpoints don't work because it is a pure SS, not a MVC project. That makes it hard for me to pinpoint the issue...but that's another story)

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

I really think that you're looking for a render action instead of what you're doing.

[ServiceStack Razor - Html.RenderAction equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028447/servicestack-razor-html-renderaction-equivalent)

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/RazorRockstars.Console.Files/Pages/PartialExamples.cshtml