# ServiceStack Razor - Html.RenderAction equivalent

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, servicestack

I have the requirement to use Html.RenderAction like you would in ASP.NET MVC.

For instance I have a Home Page with News and Products on.

I would like to do for instance

```
@Html.RenderAction("/api/products/featured")
```

Which would start a new service call and output the template to the html stream.

Is this possible using ServiceStack Razor and if so how do I accomplish it?

Comment: If you able to get the featured products in the 'Parent' View you could try something like @Html.RenderPage("FeatureProducts.cshtml", FeaturedProductsModel)

Comment: I realise that however the whole purpose of using RenderAction is so you remove the dependency on however the products are retrived.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [PartialExamples.cshtml](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/RazorRockstars.Console.Files/Pages/PartialExamples.cshtml) test page shows different examples of rendering a razor view inside a page, e.g:

Using the new `RenderToAction()` method which lets you execute a Service and it's rendered partial view with a route and QueryString, e.g:

```
@Html.RenderAction("/products/1")
```

This also takes an optional view name if you want a different view than the default:

```
@Html.RenderAction("/products/1", "CustomProductView")
```

There's also the normal `Html.Partial()` to specify which view and model you want to render in the page, e.g:

```
@Html.Partial("GetProduct", 
    base.ExecuteService<ProductService>(s => s.Any(new GetProduct { Id = 1 })))
```

`ExecuteService` is simply a wrapper around the equivalent `ResolveService` in a using statement, i.e:

```
@{
   Response response = null;
   using (var service = base.ResolveService<ProductService>())
   {
       response = service.Any(new GetProduct { Id = 1 });
   }
}
@Html.Partial("GetProduct", response)
```

The new `RenderToAction()` method in Razor Views was added in **v4.0.34+** which is now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: This additional feature now satisfies my questions requirement.

Answer (score 1):

*I may be duplicating my answer or I lost it somehow

Looking at the ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage class there is an Html property of type ServiceStack.Html.HtmlHelper. I don't see 'RenderAction' as a method (or extension method) on this class so it doesn't appear to be available. There is a 'Partial' method that takes the ViewName and an overload that takes a ViewName and an object. Based on your above comment this doesn't appear to be a useful solution.

If I'm correct about the above, I think you'd need your 'Featured View Template' to pull in the data. Could add soemthing like

```
    { FeaturedResponse products = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost").Get<FeaturedResponse>("/api/products/featured"); }
```

to your template. This would allow you to use the products variable like a Model.

Or, use JavaScript to pull the data into the template. You would have have to use JavaScript to get your data into the HTML elements, though.

You could then render the template using @Html.Partial('Featured')

Hope this helps.